# How to add a resource monitor for MATERIALIZED_VIEW_MAINTENANCE and AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING?

Tags: monitoring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, materialized-views, cost-management, clustering-key

I would like to add a Resource Monitor for monitoring the costs for MATERIALIZED_VIEW_MAINTENANCE and AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING. An email should be send if these costs above a specific threshold.

Is there any way to do it? I can only chooses ACCOUNT or WAREHOUSES to monitor.

Thanks,
VXThosch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answers is no, you cannot control the cost for Auto clustering and Materialized view through resource monitor.

Account-level resource monitor does not control credit usage by the Snowflake-provided warehouses (used for Snowpipe, automatic reclustering, and materialized views); the monitor only controls the virtual warehouses created in your account.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/resource-monitors.html#assignment-of-resource-monitors